# When ModSecurity rule 981257 activate my website won't load

Tags: joomla, cpanel, whm, mod-security, mod-security2

I am using this rule on many websites but for some reason on 1 website that rule blocks my site, i'm receiving this error

> ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

This is the security rule code

> SecRule
>   REQUEST_COOKIES|!REQUEST_COOKIES:/__utm/|REQUEST_COOKIES_NAMES|ARGS_NAMES|ARGS|XML:/*
>   "(?i:(?:,.*?)\da-f\"'`][\"'`)|(?:\Wselect.+\W*?from)|((?:select|create|rename|truncate|load|alter|delete|update|insert|desc)\s*?(\s*?space\s*?())"
>   "phase:request, rev:'2', ver:'OWASP_CRS/3.0.0', maturity:'9',
>   accuracy:'8', capture, t:none,t:urlDecodeUni, block, msg:'Detects
>   MySQL comment-/space-obfuscated injections and backtick termination',
>   id:'981257', tag:'application-multi', tag:'language-mutli',
>   tag:'platform-multi', tag:'attack-sqli',
>   tag:'OWASP_CRS/WEB_ATTACK/SQL_INJECTION', logdata:'Matched Data:
>   %{TX.0} found within %{MATCHED_VAR_NAME}: %{MATCHED_VAR}',
>   severity:'CRITICAL', setvar:'tx.msg=%{rule.msg}',
>   setvar:tx.sql_injection_score=+%{tx.critical_anomaly_score},
>   setvar:tx.anomaly_score=+%{tx.critical_anomaly_score},
>   setvar:'tx.%{rule.id}-OWASP_CRS/WEB_ATTACK/SQLI-%{matched_var_name}=%{tx.0}'"

Please advise, if you need more info i will gladly give you.

Comment: What's your SecDefaultAction block action doing? It's probably redirecting to an error page rather than denying access and when requesting the error page the browser is still sending the cookie and so it's blocked and redirect to same error page... Etc. You need to check the error logs to see why it's blocking and tune the rule.

Answer (score 0):

You will get more information about this issues in server error logs file, Ask your hosting provider to check server logs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure how this rule is working well on other websites to begin with. The thing is what is happening is that you are checking the cookies for certain blacklisted patterns and you are (possibly) doing a redirect to another page. This means that when this rule triggered, you will always end up in an infinite loop since the cookies are not erased from the browser (so, the rule will re-check the cookies and will perform the same action on each refresh).

As for the other website being blocked all the time, then it seems that you are running into a false positive causing this issue all the time, or it might be that you were testing with your cookies and the ModSecurity rule is being triggered all the time. Try clearing your cookies and see if that fixes the problem.

Like I said, there is something wrong with the logic of your ModSecurity rule so it's a good idea to re-think it.